# React.js focus on next element when submit has been pressed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I can't seem to find an answer specifically for React and the handlesubmit function.

I have a component that asks a series of questions (a Madlibs game) and I can't seem to get the focus to go to the next input after you hit submit/enter.  I'm not sure what to do to make that work in my code despite my searching here and on Google.

My code is as follows (I'm using Styled Components so for reference for my text input it's:

```
const InputStyle = styled.input`
  border: 0;
  cursor:pointer;
`;
```

as my text input

```
   class NameForm extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          value1: '',
          value2: '',
          value3: '',
          value4: '',
          value5: '',
          value6: '',
          value7: '',
          newValue: '',
          submitted: false,
          input1: 0,
          input2: 0,
          input3: 0,
          input4: 0,
          input5: 0,
          input6: 0,
          input7: 0,
          display: 'block',
          currentStep: 1
        };

    this.handleFirstChange = event => this.handleChange(event, 'value1');
    this.handleSecondChange = event => this.handleChange(event, 'value2');
    this.handleThirdChange = event => this.handleChange(event, 'value3');
    this.handleFourthChange = event => this.handleChange(event, 'value4');
    this.handleFifthChange = event => this.handleChange(event, 'value5');
    this.handleSixthChange = event => this.handleChange(event, 'value6');
    this.handleSeventhChange = event => this.handleChange(event, 'value7');
    this.handleSubmit = event => this._handleSubmit(event);
  }


  handleChange(event, type) {
    let newState = {};
    newState[type] = event.target.value;
    this.setState(newState);
  }

  _handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (this.state.currentStep > 6) {
      this.setState({ visible: !this.state.visible });
      this.setState({ display: 'none' });
    } else {
      this.setState({ currentStep: this.state.currentStep + 1 });
    }
  }

  inputHolderStyle(style, step) {
    const displayProp = step === this.state.currentStep ? 'block' : 'none';

    return {
      background: `url(${style}) no-repeat center center`,
      backgroundSize: 'cover',
      display: displayProp
    };
  }

  render() {
    const divStyle = {
      marginTop: '50px',
      color: 'white',
      top: '25px',
      position: 'absolute',
      width: '320px',
      textAlign: 'center',
      background: 'white',
      padding: '1em',
      borderRadius: '3px'
    };
    let question = null;
    const show = this.state.visible;
    if (show) {
      question = (
        <div>
          <Crawler
            properName1={this.state.value1}
            noun1={this.state.value2}
            properName2={this.state.value3}
            properName3={this.state.value4}
            noun2={this.state.value5}
            personsName1={this.state.value6}
            noun3={this.state.value7}
          />
        </div>
      );
    }
    return (
      <MainContainer>
        <div style={divStyle}>
          <form
            style={{ display: this.state.display }}
            onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
          >
            <InputHolder style={this.inputHolderStyle(ml1, 1)}>
              <InputQuestion>Enter A Proper Noun</InputQuestion>
              <label>
                <InputStyle
                  name="input1"
                  type="text"
                  value={this.state.value1}
                  placeholder="Proper Noun"
                  onChange={this.handleFirstChange}
                />
                <GrammarNerd>
                  a name used for an individual person, place, or organization, spelled with initial capital letters, e.g., Larry, Mexico, and Boston Red Sox.
                </GrammarNerd>
              </label>
            </InputHolder>
            <InputHolder style={this.inputHolderStyle(ml2, 2)}>
              <InputQuestion>Enter A Noun</InputQuestion>
              <label>
                <InputStyle
                  name="input2"
                  type="text"
                  value={this.state.value2}
                  placeholder="Noun"
                  onChange={this.handleSecondChange}
                />
                <GrammarNerd>
                  a word (other than a pronoun) used to identify any of a class of people, places, or things common noun, or to name a particular one of these proper noun.
                </GrammarNerd>
              </label>
            </InputHolder>
            <InputHolder style={this.inputHolderStyle(ml3, 3)}>
              <InputQuestion>Enter A Proper Noun</InputQuestion>
              <label>
                <InputStyle
                  name="input3"
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Enter a Proper Noun"
                  value={this.state.value3}
                  onChange={this.handleThirdChange}
                />
              </label>
              <GrammarNerd>
                a name used for an individual person, place, or organization, spelled with initial capital letters, e.g., Larry, Mexico, and Boston Red Sox.
              </GrammarNerd>
            </InputHolder>
            <InputHolder style={this.inputHolderStyle(ml3, 4)}>
              <InputQuestion>Enter A Noun</InputQuestion>
              <label>
                <InputStyle
                  name="input4"
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Enter a Proper Name"
                  value={this.state.value4}
                  onChange={this.handleFourthChange}
                />
                <GrammarNerd>
                  a word (other than a pronoun) used to identify any of a class of people, places, or things common noun, or to name a particular one of these proper noun.
                </GrammarNerd>
              </label>
            </InputHolder>
            <InputHolder style={this.inputHolderStyle(ml3, 5)}>
              <InputQuestion>Enter A Noun</InputQuestion>
              <label>
                <InputStyle
                  name="input5"
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Enter a Noun"
                  value={this.state.value5}
                  onChange={this.handleFifthChange}
                />
                <GrammarNerd>
                  a word (other than a pronoun) used to identify any of a class of people, places, or things common noun, or to name a particular one of these proper noun.
                </GrammarNerd>
              </label>
            </InputHolder>
            <InputHolder style={this.inputHolderStyle(ml3, 6)}>
              <InputQuestion>A Woman's Name</InputQuestion>
              <label>
                <InputStyle
                  name="input6"
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="A Woman's Name"
                  value={this.state.value6}
                  onChange={this.handleSixthChange}
                />
              </label>
              <GrammarNerd>
                a name used for an individual person, place, or organization, spelled with initial capital letters, e.g., Larry, Mexico, and Boston Red Sox.
              </GrammarNerd>
            </InputHolder>
            <InputHolder style={this.inputHolderStyle(ml3, 7)}>
              <InputQuestion>Noun</InputQuestion>
              <label>
                <InputStyle
                  name="input7"
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Enter a Noun"
                  value={this.state.value7}
                  onChange={this.handleSeventhChange}
                />
              </label>
              <GrammarNerd>
                a word (other than a pronoun) used to identify any of a class of people, places, or things common noun, or to name a particular one of these proper noun.
              </GrammarNerd>
            </InputHolder>
            <InputHolderSubmit>
              <SubmitButton type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </InputHolderSubmit>
          </form>
        </div>
        <NextQuestion>
          {question}
        </NextQuestion>
      </MainContainer>
    );
  }
}

export default NameForm;
```

With each question asked, the previous has it's display set to none the next one is brought up.  It works just fine but it will not focus on the text input and am unsure what to do to make that work

Comment: If all inputs were children of the same parent in DOM, it would be as easy as `•.nextSibling.focus()` (see [example](https://codepen.io/rishatmuhametshin/pen/YxpgQK)), however in your case you need to maintain the list of refs to each input to do that (see [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)).

Comment: I followed the doc and didn't get an error but it didn't work either (focus still not working).  Am I needing to assign individual refs or should all be `ref={(input) => { this.textInput = input; }} ` ?

Comment: Refs are pointers at DOM nodes, the easiest way to connect with good ol' DOM API. So just as with any other nodes, you need as many refs as many you have nodes → as many there are input elements. A Map of them or something like this.